How to test loading script with correct props
I'm loading a script for 3rd party cookie management using the <Script /> component. I want to test that it was loaded with correct language attribute. But I don't know how to test it.
RootLayout:
layout.tsx
const RootLayout = ({
  children,
}: PropsWithChildren) => {

  return (
    <html className={rubikVariable.variable} lang={language}>
      <UserProvider>
        <CookieInformation>
          <body className="body">
            ...
          </body>
        </CookieInformation>
      <UserProvider>
    <html>
  )
})

CookieInformation.tsx
'use client';

import Script from 'next/script';
import { PropsWithChildren } from 'react';

const CookieInformation = ({ children }: PropsWithChildren) => {
  const browserLang = navigator.language;

  // extracts language, ex. 'en-us' -> 'en'
  const matches = browserLang.match(/\w*(?=-)?/i);
  const language = matches?.[0] ?? 'en';

  return (
    <>
      <Script
        data-testid="cookie-script"
        data-culture={language}
        data-testid="cookie-information-script"
        id="CookieConsent"
        src="https://policy.app.cookieinformation.com/uc.js"
        strategy="lazyOnload"
      />
      {children}
    </>
  );
};

export default CookieInformation;


cookie-information.test.tsx
describe('CookieInformation', () => {
 it('should call 3rd party script with language from user agent', () => {
    const expected = 'https://policy.app.cookieinformation.com/uc.js'

    // mock language
    Object.defineProperty(global.navigator, 'language', {
      value: 'en-gb'
    });

    jest.mock('next/script', () => {
      // eslint-disable-next-line react/display-name, react/prop-types
      return function ({ children, 'data-testid': dataTestId, ...props }) {
        return (
          <script data-testid={dataTestId} {...props}>
            {children}
          </script>
        );
      };
    });

    render(
      <CookieInformation /> 
    );

    expect(document.querySelector('script)).toHaveAttribute(
      'src',
      expected
      
    );
    // expect(getByTestId('cookie-script')).toHaveAttribute('src', expected);
  });
})

But the test can't find the script and query always returns null. Doesn't matter if I remove the mock of 'next/script'. Doesn't matter if I query by test id or directly on the document.
Doing screen.debug also reveals that script are not present in test DOM.
So how can I test that script is there and have correct attributes?
